# The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values (Plesk on Windows)

Tags: javascript, windows, cors, plesk

I have the following code in JS:

```
// Function to feed the API
function FeedAPI() {
    // Define the API endpoint URL
    var apiUrl = "https://ifthenpay.com/api/gateway/paybylink/XXX-XXXX";

    // Define the JSON API body
    var apiData = {
        "id": "1234",
        "amount": ValueSelected(),
        "description": $('#name').val(),
        "lang": "en",
        "expiredate": "",
        "accounts": "",
        "selected_method": PaymentSelected()
    };
    console.log("API data: ", apiData);
    
    // Use jQuery's $.ajax() function to make the request
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: apiUrl,
        data: JSON.stringify(apiData),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            console.log("API response: ", response);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.error("Error: ", error);
        }
    });
}
```

But get this error:
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://ifthenpay.com/api/gateway/paybylink/XXX-XXXX' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed.`

I'm using Plesk on Windows and already tried to set my `web.config` file to the following:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
  </customHeaders>  
</httpProtocol>
```

At this point, I tried everything... Can someone help??

Comment: *something else* is setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, something in yuor server side code perhaps - are all the other `Access-Control-Allow-*` exactly as written above? or do they get modified too?

Comment: Yes, they are exactly as written above. I've scouted the entire Plesk pannel and I can't find anything else...

Comment: Oh, wait ... that's a response from `ifthenpay.com` - if that is not your site, then nothing you can do on your site will fix that

Comment: `ifthenpay.com` has told me that this is defenatly an issue on my side. I'm confused.

Comment: how odd, it's their server sending invalid CORS headers - not sure why you even bothered with the plesk config on your server since that is irrelevant - I would assure `itthenpay` that your config has nothing to do with what their server sends in a response

Answer (score 0):

So, I fixed my issue by just changinging the method of the API Integration to "GET".

Here is the code:

```
function FeedAPI() {
// Define the API endpoint URL
var apiUrl = "https://ifthenpay.com/api/gateway/paybylink/get";

// Define the query parameters
var apiParams = {
    "gatewaykey": "XXX-XXXX",
    "id": "1234",
    "amount": ValueSelected(),
    "description": $('#name').val(),
    "lang": "en",
    "expiredate": "",
    "accounts": "XXX|YYY;MBWAY|XXX-XXXXX",
    "selected_method": PaymentSelected()
};

console.log("API params: ", apiParams);

// Use jQuery's $.ajax() function to make the request
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: apiUrl,
    data: apiParams,
    success: function(response) {
        console.log("API response: ", response);
        window.open(response.link, "_blank");
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.error("Error: ", error);
    }
});
}
```